# Multiple Figures "Tile" Plot in Sage

Tags: plot, graph, figure, sage

I'm wondering how I can make figures or plots like this one in Sage, if it's possible:

[image: elliptic curves]

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sage builds on `matplotlib` which by itself allows you to do pretty much anything you can imagine. See http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot.html.

Comment: Ohhh, I hadn't seen plot.graphics_array() or at least didn't remember it.

Comment: Yes, `graphics_array` is what you want - but watch out for https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/10657 when it comes to options.